# Auto Layout stick to bottom

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying Auto layout for the first time and I'm stuck.

I would like an UIPageControl get stick to the bottom of my screen for 3.5 inch and 4 inch screen.
I tried to apply a Bottom Space to Container constraint but it doesn't work. My 3.5 inch screen doesn't display it.

[image]

Do you know what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: post  your screen shot

Comment: You sholud have yellow autolayout warnings. Set also top and trailing space or width and height.

Comment: How do you know its not being displayed? Give it a background color and see if it shows up. By default pagecontrol has transparent background color. And if # of page is 0, then you will not see it. use visual debugging tool like https://github.com/lukaswelte/DCIntrospect-ARC to debug layout issues

Comment: @mamnun I hardcoded number of page for debbug. and it appears on 4-inch screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like that :

[image]

Take care to put constraint to your `parentView` if it's not the `root view` of your `UIViewController`

Comment: Here my parent view is my UIViewController's view. I can't find how you put the long vertical bar ? What type of constraint is it ?

Comment: `Horizontal Center in Container`

Comment: Ok done I have the same schema as yours but doesn't work. 3.5 inch screen hide my control

Comment: Did you try to use the simulation of 3.5inch form in your storyboard to see what's happened ?

Comment: Ok I think I figured out why I have a problem : My UIViewController's view is not resizing it self. It's always at 568 px height. Don't know why ...

Answer (score -2):

try to uncheck the Auto Layout option like below

[image]

i think it will help you..